# Regressions - variable effect

Tags: regression-coefficients

This is more of a theoretical question than concerning a specific data set.

Say that I have a dependent variable Y and want to check if 4 different explanatory variables X1, X2, X3 and X4 has an effect on Y - what would then be the best way of doing this:

- Should I start with a multiple regression model where Y = B_0 + B_1X_1 + B_2X_2 + B_3X_3 + B_4X_4 and see which beta estimates are significant or,
- Should I run 4 different regressions models with only one explanatory variable at a time; Y = B_0 + B_1X_1, Y = B_0 + B_1X_2...? And see which regression models are significant?

Or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends what your goal is.

Do you want to be able to say something about the expected effect of $X_i$ on your response only? For example, something like "We expect that the response will increase by 3 units when $X_1$ increases by one unit"? If that's the case you can fit models independently.

The danger with this is that you can't aggregate your conclusions because of collinearity.  It's possible both $X_1$ and $X_2$ have a similar effect on your response, because they essentially measure the same thing.  So you can say something about the effect of $X_1$ on your response, and you can say something about the effect of $X_2$ on your response, but you won't be able to say anything about the effect of $X_1$ and $X_2$ on your response simultaneously.

In other words, it may be the case that $X_1$ has an effect on your response individually, and $X_2$ has an effect on your response individually, but when considered together, only one of the variables really matters.  So if you fit individual models, you won't be able to report something like "$X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ and $X_4$ all have a significant effect on the response."  They may each affect the response individually, but you don't know that they're all significant when considered together, and you'll need to make sure that's clear when reporting your results.

If you want to have a model that best accounts for all of the data, and gives you the best estimate for the response possible, you should start by fitting a model with all of the variables.  Then follow a process of removing variables that are not significant, removing variables that are collinear, and finding a "best fit" model.  Once you have a model with multiple variables, you can make conclusions about the effect of all the variables simultaneously (though you have to hold all but one of them constant for inferring on the coefficients).  For example, you'll be able to say something like "If we hold $X_1, X_3$, and $X_4$ constant, and increase $X_2$ by 3 units, we expect the response will increase by 2 units." Or something like "When considered together, we see that $X_1$ is significant in predicting the response, but $X_2$ is not", etc.

Comment: This is good up to the advice of "removing  variables that are not significant, removing variables that are collinear."  Both procedures are fraught with pitfalls and are known generally not to produce good models.  See threads on our site about "variable selection" and "model building."

Comment: But there is a process of deciding which variables to keep in the model, and checking collinearity and significance of the coefficients is part of that, no? Would you instead say something like "consider which variables should remain in the model, after checking and taking into account collinearity and significance of the coefficients?"  Or are you saying to just keep all of the variables in the model regardless?

Comment: I wouldn't say either of those things, particularly because significance (p-values) is misleading for this purpose and checking collinearity is much subtler than just considering individual variables. There are many approaches to this and they depend on many factors including the purposes of modeling, what might be known about the potential roles played by these factors, the nature of any multicollinearity, the number of variables being considered, the number of observations, and more.

Comment: Thank you, that was a really good answer!